# Vagrant SSH works but ssh vagrant@192.168.33.10 does not - has my IP changed?

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I am using a MacBook Pro running OSX, with Vagrant 1.9.1

I've had my vagrant box running just fine for about 5 months.  And it still works fine (and my `Vagrantfile` has not changed, it still specifies an IP of 192.168.33.10) - EXCEPT I cannot connect through that IP address.

I don't know where to begin or how to figure out what's changed.  I suspect something else has "hijacked" that IP but I don't know how to check it.  I can no longer access my localhost websites, and my Sequel Pro tunnel no longer works?  What has happened, and how can I a) detect it and b) fix it?  Thanks

-- UPDATE --

I found this command:

```
vagrant ssh -c "hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f2" 2>/dev/null
```

which did indeed say `192.168.33.10` - but when I try to ping that, it does not respond (nor, again, do my virtual host sites or Sequel Pro tunnel)

Comment: are you able to ssh into the instance via vagrant ssh ?? If so, please run `ip a` and verify that the vagrant box has the ip 192.168.33.10

Comment: After my change above, login output says `IP address for eth1: 192.168.33.11`; however `ip a` says: `inet 192.168.33.11/24 brd 192.168.33.255 scope global eth1`.  Again, what has happened is not clear, but the system seems to have accepted the .11 IP OK